# lambda GET/POST request direct to endpoint without being http?

Tags: aws-lambda

We have 2 internal endpoints that do not have CORs. sending a GET/POST request via postman and curl work just fine.  But when I try to setup a lambda to hit these end points, it fails sue to being an HTTP request.  I tried NodeJS Fetch 9which is HTTP) and also using python request.post/request.get but those are also HTTP requests..

Anyone know a way to accomplish this in a lambda function?

My latest failed attempt:

```
import json
import requests

EMAIL_RAW_PATH = '/Validation_API_Stage/email_address'
ADDRESS_RAW_PATH = '/Validation_API_Stage/address'
EMAIL_URL = 'https://ent-sls-email-validation.msd0xxxx.example.com/v1/validationInfo'
ADDRESS_URL = 'https://address.msdxxxx.example.com/data/address_scrub'

ADDRESS_HEADERS = {
    "lob": "Test",
    "application-name": "Example",
    "tenant-id": "16",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

EMAIL_HEADERS = {
    'x-correlation-id': '1234567',
    'lob': 'Test',
    'application-name': 'Example',
    'tenant-id': '20',
    'x-api-key': '12345678901234567890',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    if event['rawPath'] == ADDRESS_RAW_PATH:
        ADDRESS_BODY = event['body']
        response = requests.post(ADDRESS_URL, headers=ADDRESS_HEADERS, json=ADDRESS_BODY)
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "Response ": response
        })
    }
    elif event['rawPath'] == EMAIL_RAW_PATH:
        decodedEvent = json.loads(event['body'])
        EMAIL_ADDRESS = decodedEvent['email']
        
        URL = EMAIL_URL + '?email=' + EMAIL_ADDRESS
        response = requests.get(URL, headers=EMAIL_HEADERS)
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "Response ": response
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was it was not attached to a VPC, once I did that it started working..